# How to .put() data in the first item in a JsonStore() in Python Kivy

Tags: python, json, kivy

I'm creating an app which involves a table using Kivy with the module [storage](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.storage.html?highlight=storage). Every time I `.put()` something in the Json file, I want that certain data to appear just below the headings of the table. Meaning I want the table to show first the most recent data. My code that displays the table is like this:

```
table.add_widget(Label(text="Heading 1"))
table.add_widget(Label(text="Heading 2"))
table.add_widget(Label(text="Heading 3"))

for item in database:
    data1= database.get(item)['data1']
    data2 = database.get(item)['data2']
    data3 = database.get(item)['data3']

    table.add_widget(Label(text=data1))
    table.add_widget(Label(text=data2))
    table.add_widget(Label(text=data3))
```

Notes:

- `table` is a Gridlayout
- `database` is the Json file

My first solution is to `reversed()` the for-loop but it will not work because `database` is not a dictionary nor a list because it is a `JsonStore()`.

My second solution is to `.put()` the data in front of the Json file like this:

```
{"added_data": {"data1": "info1", "data2": "info2", "data3": "info3"}, "old_data": {"data1": "info1", "data2": "info2", "data3": "info3"}}
```

but I don't know how to do this.

So... how do you `.put()` the data in front? or is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`add_widget` method accepts an `index` argument which allows you to decide where to put new Widget, so instead to try changing order of data you can just insert new entries in a selected place. An example code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

kv = '''
#:import Label kivy.uix.label.Label

<TestWidget>
    orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        Button:
            text: 'add before'
            on_press: root.add_widget(Label(text="before"), index=len(root.children))
        Button:
            text: 'add after'
            on_press: root.add_widget(Label(text="after"))
'''
Builder.load_string(kv)

class TestWidget(BoxLayout):
    pass

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return TestWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

An example with a `GridLayout` table:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

kv = '''
#:import Label kivy.uix.label.Label
#:import randint random.randint

<TestWidget>
    cols: 3
    Button:
        text: 'add first'
        on_press: 
            root.add_widget(Label(text=str(randint(0, 10))), index=len(root.children)-3)
            root.add_widget(Label(text=str(randint(0, 10))), index=len(root.children)-3)
            root.add_widget(Label(text=str(randint(0, 10))), index=len(root.children)-3)
    Widget
    Button:
        text: 'add last'
        on_press: 
            root.add_widget(Label(text=str(randint(0, 10))))
            root.add_widget(Label(text=str(randint(0, 10))))
            root.add_widget(Label(text=str(randint(0, 10))))
'''
Builder.load_string(kv)

class TestWidget(GridLayout):
    pass

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return TestWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the late reply because I got sick. :-)